# Get passing argument at python decorator

Tags: python, inspect

```
def deco_test(func):
    def inner_function(*args, **kwargs):
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
    return inner_function

@deco_test
def a(a='asdf', b='asdf'):
    pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    a(456, 789)
    a(123, b='qwer/123/a.txt')
    a(a='098', b='789456')
```

I want to get argument like this:

1. {'a': 456, 'b': 789}
2. {'a': 123, 'b': 'qwer/123/a.txt'}
3. {'a': '098', 'b':'789456'}

in `deco_test(func)`

Answer (score 0):

You will not get access to the parameter you provide to `a` inside `deco_test`. The decoration is done when the function is declared, before you call the function and at that point in time you have no information about those arguments.

Inside the `inner_function` you get arguments as provided in the decorated function call `a(456, 789)` will give you `args=(456, 789)`. If you want to format them according to the arguments that `a` can take, I think you have to inspect on the function `a`.